# java.io.EOFException when serialize object from child process and try to de-serialize from parent process ProcessBuilder

Tags: java, serialization, deserialization, processbuilder

I am creating a new process using java `ProcessBuider` and I want an object to be sent to the parent from the creating child. Here, I serialize the object from child side and send it to the parent. But when I read the sent object from parent, there is an exception saying

```
java.io.EOFException
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream$PeekInputStream.readFully(Unknown Source)
```

Felt like still there are no streams receive to the parent when I am trying to read that.`Parent, Child` and the Sending object java files are detailed below.

DTO.java

```
public class DTO implements Serializable{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private String name;

    public DTO(String name)
    {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

@Override
    public int hashCode() {}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {}
```

Parent.java

```
public class Parent {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

      try {
          new Parent().start();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

      public void start() throws IOException, InterruptedException, ClassNotFoundException
      {
            String classpath = System.getProperty("java.class.path");
            String className = Child.class.getCanonicalName();

            ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder(
                "java", "-cp", classpath, className);

            builder.inheritIO();
            Process process = builder.start();

            if (process.isAlive()) {

                ObjectInputStream input = new ObjectInputStream(process.getInputStream());
                DTO dto = (DTO)input.readObject();
                System.out.println();

            }
      }
}
```

Child.java

```
public class Child {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        DTO dto = new DTO("text");

        ObjectOutputStream stream = new ObjectOutputStream(System.out);
        stream.writeObject(dto);
        stream.flush();
        stream.close();
    }
}
```

What is the wrong that I am doing here ? Any suggestions to fix this

Comment: I was unable to reproduce your problem. It seems probable that the `java` command failed. Read the error stream and find out.

Comment: see the full exception. Parent.java line 40 means the initiating ObjectInputStream object line
                                                                                  
 java.io.EOFException
 at java.io.ObjectInputStream$PeekInputStream.readFully(Unknown Source)
 at java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.readShort(Unknown Source)
 at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readStreamHeader(Unknown Source)
 at java.io.ObjectInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
 at working.Parent.start(Parent.java:40)
 at working.Parent.main(Parent.java:19)

Comment: Exactly, so the child process never ran at all, so it never created the object output stream, so no stream header, so you got your exception. Probably a CLASSPATH problem.

Comment: This start working when you remove the "builder.inheritIO();" code segment in the parent class. Removing this, we stop being used the same standard input and output in both the parent and child process

Answer (score 0):

This starts working when you remove the `builder.inheritIO();` code segment from parent where removing that indicates both child and parent will no longer shared a common standard I/O. Both child and parent will have different standard I/Os