# java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid stream header when writing to the stdout in child while communicating child and parent, ProcessBuilder

Tags: java, io, processbuilder, objectinputstream

I have a code segment where a new child process is created and some of the new process operation results are required to be sent to the parent process from child. Therefore I create a new ObjectOutputStream to the standard output from child class `ObjectOutputStream stream = new ObjectOutputStream(System.out);` and serialize the objects from the child process and send to the parent and the de-serialization is done within the parent.

It works fine with no issues. But the problem comes when I try to use `System.out.println()` in the child code where it is also writing to the standard output. Parent process try to de-serialize `System.out.println()` also and then there will be exceptions in the parent.

Classes are detailed below

```
public class DTO implements Serializable{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private String name;

    public DTO()
    {
        this.name = "name";
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

@Override
    public int hashCode() {}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {}
```

Parent.java

```
public class Parent {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

      try {
          new Parent().start();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

      public void start() throws IOException, InterruptedException, ClassNotFoundException
      {
            String classpath = System.getProperty("java.class.path");
            String className = Child.class.getCanonicalName();

            ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder(
                "java", "-cp", classpath, className);

            Process process = builder.start();

            if (process.isAlive()) {

                ObjectInputStream input = new ObjectInputStream(process.getInputStream());
                DTO dto = (DTO)input.readObject();

            }
      }
}
```

Child.java

```
public class Child {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        DTO dto = new DTO();

        System.out.println("printing random text here");

        ObjectOutputStream stream = new ObjectOutputStream(System.out);
        stream.writeObject(dto);
        stream.flush();
        stream.close();
    }
}
```

Exception

```
java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid stream header: 64617364
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readStreamHeader(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at working.Parent.start(Parent.java:35)
    at working.Parent.main(Parent.java:14)
```

please note that if we remove the `System.out.println()` used in the child.java, the program will execute without errors. As I think this happens because both the serialization and the `sysout` are writing to the standard output, the parent thinks it can de-serialize both. Any suggestion to fix this or a different type of approach to do this would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You corrupted the stream, by writing a string to it directly. So you got a `StreamCorruptedException`. No surprise there. You can't do that. You can't deserialize an object stream that also contains random interpolated `System.out.println()`s. This should be obvious.

> Any suggestion to fix this

Yes. Don't do it.

> or alternative approach

Alternative approach to what?

You simply have to *decide* what you're using `System.out` for. *Either* it is an object output stream *or* it is used to print text to. Not both at the same time.

NB You have still not put in any code to read the errror stream as I told you [last time you posted this code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50438445/java-io-eofexception-when-serialize-object-from-child-process-and-try-to-de-seri). You can't deploy code without error checking.